# writing to a file using for loop in c programming

Tags: c

```
struct customer information[6];

int count,loop;

printf("How many records do you want to add?\n");
scanf("%d",&loop);

FILE *ptr;
ptr = fopen("information.txt","w+");
if(!ptr)
{
  printf("file could not be opened\n");
  getchar();
  return -1;
}

for(count=1; count<=10; count++)
{
  printf("Please enter the customer's id number:\n");
  scanf("%d",&information[6].idnum);
  printf("Please enter the customer's first name and last name:\n");
  scanf("%s%s",information[6].Fname,information[6].Lname);
  printf("Please enter the customer's car model type:\n");
  scanf("%s",information[6].cartyp);
  printf("Please enter the customer's license plate number:\n");
  scanf("%s",information[6].Licnum);
  printf("Please enter the customer's car difficulty:\n");
  scanf("%s",information[6].Crdffcty);

fprintf(ptr,"%d\%s\%s\%s\%s\%s\n",information[6].idnum,information[6].Fname,         
information[6].Lname,information[6].cartyp,information[6].Licnum,
information[6].Crdffcty);

if(loop==count)
{ 
    continue;
}
}

fclose(ptr);
}
```

i am trying to write to a file using for loop but when i run the code the program doesn't loop more than one times. An error message comes up saying the program stopped working and nothing is in the text document created. i tried some of the suggestions on this site but it seems there is something else wrong with the coding. there are no errors or warning messages. Can someone tell me what i did wrong?

Comment: index of `6` is wrong.

Comment: `struct customer information[6];` has 6 items, you access the element at index 6, which is the seventh element.

Answer (score 0):

You have your struct defined with 6, and you are trying to access index 6, that is the 7th element. So, you have to make this, supposing that you want the last element:

```
struct customer information[6];

int count,loop;

printf("How many records do you want to add?\n");
scanf("%d",&loop);

FILE *ptr;
ptr = fopen("information.txt","w+");
if(!ptr)
{
  printf("file could not be opened\n");
  getchar();
  return -1;
}

for(count=1; count<=10; count++)
{
  printf("Please enter the customer's id number:\n");
  scanf("%d",&information[5].idnum);
  printf("Please enter the customer's first name and last name:\n");
  scanf("%s%s",information[5].Fname,information[5].Lname);
  printf("Please enter the customer's car model type:\n");
  scanf("%s",information[5].cartyp);
  printf("Please enter the customer's license plate number:\n");
  scanf("%s",information[5].Licnum);
  printf("Please enter the customer's car difficulty:\n");
  scanf("%s",information[5].Crdffcty);

fprintf(ptr,"%d\%s\%s\%s\%s\%s\n",information[5].idnum,information[5].Fname,         
information[5].Lname,information[6].cartyp,information[5].Licnum,
information[5].Crdffcty);

if(loop==count)
{ 
    continue;
}
}

fclose(ptr);
}
```